# Php weak random value generator for cases where repeated values are useful

Tags: php, random

I am generating test data for use in my frontend and I want to generate ages. Currently I am generating age between 18 and 100 using `rand(1,100)` like this:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();

$superstars = array("Adam Cole","Finn Balor","Pete Dunne","Jordan Devlin","Noam Dar");
$fan_favourite_superstar_name = $superstars[ mt_rand( 0, count($superstars) -1 ) ];

$cities = array("London","Manchester","Leeds","Bristol");
$fan_location = $cities[ mt_rand( 0, count($cities) -1 ) ];

$the_models = array("Iphone","Nokia","Huawei","Samsung");
$fan_phone_model = $the_models[ mt_rand( 0, count($the_models) -1 ) ];


$array = Array (
    "0" => Array (
        "id" => uniqid(),
        "fan_favourite_superstar_name" => $fan_favourite_superstar_name,
        "fan_location" => $fan_location,
        "fan_phone_model" => $fan_phone_model,
        "fan_name" => $faker->name,
        "fan_age" => rand(18,100),
        "fan_comments" => $faker->text,
        "fan_picture" => rand(1,500),
        "last_updated" => time() + rand(1,1000),
    ),
```

However, I would like my ages to repeat although not completely. Is there a weak randomness generator apart from rand that can ensure that the an ages generated randomly repeat themselves n times?.

Comment: @Andreas that was a typo and i have edited.

Comment: Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php this will help getting more random results.. wait I just read it again. You want it to repeat? How many times?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "randomly repeat"? Do you want the same order X times or the same set of values in different random orders X times or what else?

Comment: @ArSeN if for a generated value 21, it should repeat say 20 times in a pool of 1 to 500. The mechanics of what is chosen to  repeat should be decided by the library or function. Something like that.

Comment: So basically you just want some random data with repetitions and don't care what mechanism is creating that repetition? Then why not just add values a random number of times and randomize the whole set? Or are you asking if there is library that does exactly that for you?

Comment: You just can create array with ages repeated as much as you wish for each value, then just randomly select any value and `unset()` this element of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function just to show my suggestion of solution:

```php
function getAge($start = 18, $end = 100, $repeat = 20){
    $result = null;
    static $ages = array();
    if ( empty($ages) ) {
        for ($i= $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
            for($j = 0; $j < $repeat; $j++)
            $ages[] = $i;
        }
    }
    $index = rand(0, count($ages));
    $result = $ages[ $index ];
    unset($ages[ $index ]);
    $ages = array_values($ages);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Checking it out. I want to arrange the output descending to see what repeats.

Comment: I think you can add one more static array to count outputted repetitions